# Searching Polymorhic models in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have these models:

```
Class Party < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partyable, polymorphic: true
end

Class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :party, as: :partyable, dependent: :destroy
end

Class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :party, as: :partyable, dependent: : destroy
end
```

witch look at these tables:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :gender
      t.text :notes
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :organizations do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :description
      t.text :notes
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateParties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :parties do |t|
      t.references :partyable, polymorphic: true
      t.text :notes
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I want to search the Party model and return an array of Parties with the given string in the name (if the party is an Organization) or the last_name (if the party is a Person)

For the moment, when I try to query the people I have no success:

```
Party.joins("INNER JOIN people ON people.id = parties.partyable_id").select('parties.*,people.last_name').where('last_name like ?', "%Smith%").first
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: last_name: SELECT  parties.*,people.last_name FROM "parties" INNER JOIN people ON people.id = parties.partyable_id WHERE (last_name like '%Smith%') ORDER BY "parties"."id" ASC LIMIT ?
```

Why can't it find the last_name column? Can I somehow improve the models to get what I want? Can anybody please give me an advice/hint/solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! typical typing error. I typed *las_name* instead of *last_name*. So one solution that is working is:

in models/Party.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  r1 = joins("INNER JOIN people ON people.id = parties.partyable_id").where('last_name like ?', "%#{search}%")
  r2 = joins("INNER JOIN organizations ON organizations.id = parties.partyable_id).where('name like ?', "%#{search}%")
  r = r1 + r2
  r.uniq{|x| x.id}
end
```

## edit

I found a better solution

```
scope :search, ->(s) {
    joins("LEFT JOIN people ON people.id = parties.partyable_id").
    joins("LEFT JOIN organizations ON organizations.id = parties.partyable_id").
    where(people.last_name LIKE :s OR organizations.name LIKE :s', s: "%#{s}%")
  }
```

Can someone provide a better method?